# Integrate PeerServer in NestJS application

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to combine peer server with my nestjs application. Unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. I am creating a service containing the peer server instance and initialize it on application start. I also use this service to handle requests coming
in a specific controller. I did the configuration as follow:

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { I18nMiddleware } from 'nestjs-i18n';
import { Logger, LoggerErrorInterceptor } from 'nestjs-pino';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { PeerServerService } from './peer-server/peer-server.service';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma/prisma.service';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
    bufferLogs: true,
  });
  app.useLogger(app.get(Logger));
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggerErrorInterceptor());
  app.use(I18nMiddleware);
  const prismaService = app.get(PrismaService);
  const peerServerService = app.get(PeerServerService);
  prismaService.enableShutdownHooks(app);
  peerServerService.enablePeerServer(app);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

peer-server.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { ExpressPeerServer, PeerServerEvents } from 'peer';
import { Express } from 'express';
@Injectable()
export class PeerServerService {
  peerServer: Express & PeerServerEvents;
  enablePeerServer(app: NestExpressApplication) {
    this.peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(app.getHttpServer(), {
      path: '/myapp',
    });
    console.log('peer server: ', this.peerServer);
    this.peerServer.get('/test', (req, res) => {
      res.send('hello');
    });
  }
}
```

peer-server.controller.ts

```
import { All, Controller, Next, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { PeerServerService } from './peer-server.service';

@Controller('/peer-server')
export class PeerServerController {
  constructor(private readonly peerServerService: PeerServerService) {}

  @All('*')
  server(
    @Req() request: Request,
    @Res() response: Response,
    @Next() next: NextFunction,
  ) {
    const entryPointPath = '/peer-server/';
    request.url = request.url.replace(entryPointPath, '/');
    console.log('in route peer: ', request.url);
    this.peerServerService.peerServer(request, response, next);
  }
}
```

I verified that the server is correctly forwarded to the peer service with this request

```
this.peerServer.get('/test', (req, res) => {
      res.send('hello');
    });
```

Sending a request to `/peer-server/test` works but `/peer-server/myapp` returns 404

Has anyone ever done that successfully ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Peer server team released a new version with documentation concerning this very issue. You can find it [here](https://docs.peerjs.com/server/frameworks/nestjs).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
import { ExpressPeerServer } from 'peer';

function bootstrap() {
  // ...

  const server = app.getHttpServer();
  const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server);
  app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);
  app.listen();

  // ...
}
```